# Unable to move file to packages directory-socialengine addons core plugin

Tags: socialengine

While uploading the socialengine addon's core plugin (module-seaocore-4.2.9p1.tar) through package manager, I am getting an error

```
 Unable to move file to packages directory. 
Please set chmod 0777 on the temporary/package/archives directory.
```

But, if we try to upload any other plugin, it will get extracted in the normal way.

I have checked the file permission and it is already 777.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue by uplading the tar file to temporary/package/packages and extracted it to the folder with the name module-seaocore-4.2.9p1.
Then deleted the tar file and went to package manager and installed the plugin.

Answer (score 5):

Uploading the tar to temporary/package/packages and extracting it into a folder (final path:  temporary/package/packages/module-seaocore-4.2.9p1) does not always work for me.

However, the following steps do seem to work if you have chmod 777 permission set on both your temporary/package/packages and temporary/packages/archives directories:

1. Try the installation and let it fail with the above error message
2. Upload the tar to temporary/package/archives
3. Go back to the Manage Packages & Plugins screen in the SE admin panel, and then click Install New Packages
4. It will find the tar in temporary/package/archives, process the extraction to temporary/package/packages, and let you install

I've replicated this a number of times now, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this,

Extract the ".tar file" and then open the "applications" folder and you will find 3 folder "languages, modules, packages" copy all the files and folders you find in these folders and paste them to the respective "application" folder in your working directory,

**remember**

After copying them again give the chmod - R 0777 permission to you package directory of working folder.

sudo chmod -R 0777 packages/

Now you can find an option to install the plugin in "Manage Plugin" section in the admin pannel.